# suexec error configuring mod_fastcgi with apache2.2.3 on centos

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, fastcgi, suexec

I've been following this [blog post](http://www.brandonturner.net/blog/2009/07/fastcgi_with_php_opcode_cache/) so that I can share APC opcode cache between PHP processes using FastCGI.  Unfortunately I'm getting the following error when starting httpd:

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_fastcgi.conf:
FastCgiWrapper: "/usr/sbin/suexec" execute access for server (uid -1, gid -1) failed: execute not allowed
```

Line 4 of mod_fastcgi.conf has `FastCgiWrapper On`. I notice that the documentation states that this line could [specify the path to the wrapper](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/25#FastCgiWrapper).  Should that be changed?

I've checked that the permissions of the user's php-fastcgi script (`550`) and directory (`555`) are correct, /usr/sbin/suexec is correct (`-r-s--x---`) and that suEXEC is being loaded by apache (`[notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)`).

Where else should I be looking?  I'm pretty sure that this is a permissions or path issue...

TIA,
JD

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with the order of the directives. In `conf/http.conf` it includes `conf.d/*` before it specifies `User` and `Group` directives.

Try putting `mod_fastcgi.conf` in `conf/` and at the end of `httpd.conf` append

```
Include conf/mod_fastcgi.conf
```